# SwiftUI: How it refreshes view and why @Published ObservableObject properties works randomly

Tags: validation, swiftui, textfield, combine, observableobject

SwiftUI seems to me more and more confusing in the way it works. 
At first glance it seams fast and easy to grasp. But if you add more and more views
something that seems to be simple starts to behave very odd and take many time to solve.

I have `Input` field with validation. This is customized input with that I can reuse in many places. But on different screens this can work totally different and totally unreliable.

**View with form**

```
struct LoginView { 

@ObservedObject private var viewModel = LoginViewModel()

var body: some View { 
VStack(spacing: 32) {

                    Spacer()

                    LabeledInput(label: "Email", input: self.$viewModel.email, isNuemorphic: true, rules: LoginFormRules.email, validation: self.$viewModel.emailValidation)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .frame(height: 50)

                    LabeledInput(label: "Password", isSecure: true, input: self.$viewModel.password, isNuemorphic: true, rules: LoginFormRules.password, validation: self.$viewModel.passwordValidation)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    .keyboardType(.asciiCapable)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .frame(height: 50)

                    self.makeSubmitButton()

                    Spacer()

                }
}
```

**LabeledInput - resuable custom input view with validation support**

```
struct LabeledInput: View {

    // MARK: - Properties
    let label: String?
    let isSecure: Bool

    // MARK: - Binding
    @Binding var input: String
    var isEditing: Binding<Bool>?

    // MARK: - Actions
    private let onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    private let onCommit: () -> Void

    // MARK: - Validation
    @ObservedObject var validator: FieldValidator<String>

    // MARK: - Init
    init(label: String? = nil,
         isSecure: Bool = false,
         input: Binding<String>,
         isEditing: Binding<Bool>? = nil,

         // validation
         rules: [Rule<String>] = [],
         validation: Binding<Validation>? = nil,

         // actions
         onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in },
         onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {

        self.label = label
        self.isSecure = isSecure
        self._input = input
        self.isEditing = isEditing


        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
        self.onCommit = onCommit


        self.validator = FieldValidator(input: input, rules: rules, validation: validation ?? .constant(Validation()))
    }

    var useUIKit: Bool {
        self.isEditing != nil
    }

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {


                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 1)
                .foregroundColor(!self.validator.validation.isEdited ? Color("LightGray")
                    : self.validator.validation.isValid ? Color("Green") : Color("Red"))
                    .frame(maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 16)


                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        self.makeLabel()
                            .offset(x: self.isNuemorphic ? 0 : 16,
                                    y: self.isNuemorphic ? 0 : 8)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }

                self.makeField()
                .frame(maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: self.isNuemorphic ? 20 : 16)
                .padding(10)
            }
        }

    }

    private func makeField() -> some View {
        Group {
            if useUIKit {
                self.makeUIKitTextField(secure: self.isSecure)
            } else {
                if self.isSecure {
                    self.makeSecureField()
                } else {
                    self.makeTextField()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func makeLabel() -> some View {
        Group {
            if label != nil {
                Text("\(self.label!.uppercased())")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: self.isNuemorphic ? 13 : 11))
                    .foregroundColor(!self.validator.validation.isEdited ? Color("DarkBody")
                        : self.validator.validation.isValid ? Color("Green") : Color("Red"))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 8)

            } else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }

    private func makeSecureField() -> some View {

        SecureField("", text: self.$input, onCommit: {
            self.validator.onCommit()
            self.onCommit()
        })
        .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
            .foregroundColor(Color("DarkBody"))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }

    private func makeTextField() -> some View {

        TextField("", text: self.$input, onEditingChanged: { editing in

            self.onEditingChanged(editing)
            self.validator.onEditing(editing)

            if !editing { self.onCommit() }

        }, onCommit: {
            self.validator.onCommit()
            self.onCommit()

        })
        .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
            .foregroundColor(Color("DarkBody"))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }

    private func makeUIKitTextField(secure: Bool) -> some View {

        let firstResponderBinding = Binding<Bool>(get: {
            self.isEditing?.wrappedValue ?? false //?? self.isFirstResponder
        }, set: {
            //self.isFirstResponder = $0
            self.isEditing?.wrappedValue = $0
        })

        return UIKitTextField(text: self.$input, isEditing: firstResponderBinding, font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15)!, textColor: UIColor(named: "DarkBody")!, placeholder: "", onEditingChanged: { editing in

            self.onEditingChanged(editing)
            self.validator.onEditing(editing)

        }, onCommit: {

            self.validator.onCommit()
            self.onCommit()
        })
    }
}
```

**And here is how I store model (input values and validation) in ObservableObject i.e. LoginViewModel.**

```
final class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: - Published
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""

    @Published var emailValidation: Validation = Validation(onEditing: true)
    @Published var passwordValidation: Validation = Validation(onEditing: true)

    @Published var validationErrors: [String]? = nil
    @Published var error: DescribableError? = nil

}
```

When I use this code depending on how I create ViewModel (in LoginView property or injected to LoginView constructor) depending on view parent views (screens) it is embedded can work totally different can cause hours of debugging and unexpected behaviour.

1. Sometimes it seems that there is 1 ViewModel instance sometimes it seems that this instance is created with each View refresh
2. sometimes LabeledInput body is refreshing and validation colouring of label works corretly. Other times it seems it does not refresh at all and nothing happens
3. sometimes refreshes so often keyboard is immediately hiding
4. Other times there is no validation at all
5. Other times input is lost after exiting field or when rotating phone landscape to portrait
6. If there is some event that causes parent view refresh it can cause the inputs to lose data and validation.
7. Sometimes it refreshes to often other times it doesn't refresh at all as it should.

I've tried to add .id(UUID) , custom .id(refreshId) or other Equatable protocol implementations but it doesn't work as expected to be reusable customized input with validation reusable between multiple forms on multiple screens.

Here is simple validation struct

```
struct Validation {

    let onEditing: Bool

    init(onEditing: Bool = false) {
        self.onEditing = onEditing
    }

    var isEdited: Bool = false
    var errors: [String] = []
}
```

And here FieldValidator ObservableObject

```
class FieldValidator<T>: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: - Properties
    private let rules: [Rule<T>]

    // MARK: - Binding
    @Binding private var input: T
    @Binding var validation: Validation

    // MARK: - Init
    init(input: Binding<T>, rules: [Rule<T>], validation: Binding<Validation>) {
        #if DEBUG
        print("[FieldValidator] init: \(input.wrappedValue)")
        #endif

        self._input = input
        self.rules = rules
        self._validation = validation 
    }

     private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
}

// MARK: - Public API
extension FieldValidator {

    func validateField() {

        validation.errors = rules
            .filter { !$0.isAsync }
            .filter { !$0.validate(input) }
            .map { $0.errorMessage() }
    }

    func validateFieldAsync() {

        rules
            .filter { $0.isAsync }
            .forEach { rule in

                rule.validateAsync(input)
                .filter { valid  in
                    !valid
                }.sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                    self.validation.errors.append(rule.errorMessage())
                })
                .store(in: &disposables)
            }
    }
}

// MARK: - Helper Public API
extension FieldValidator {

    func onEditing(_ editing: Bool) {

        self.validation.isEdited = true

        if editing {
            if self.validation.onEditing {
                self.validateField()
            }
        } else {
            // on end editing
            self.validateField()
            self.validateFieldAsync()
        }
    }

    func onCommit() {
        self.validateField()
        self.validateFieldAsync()
    }
}
```

Rules are just subclasses of

```
class Rule<T>  {

    var isAsync: Bool { return false }

    func validate(_ value: T) -> Bool { return false }
    func errorMessage() -> String { return "" }

    func validateAsync(_ value: T) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        fatalError("Async validation is not implemented!")
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Complete UIKitTextField example

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct UIKitTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    // MARK: - Observed
    @ObservedObject private var keyboardEvents = KeyboardEvents()

    // MARK: - Binding
    @Binding var text: String
    var isEditing: Binding<Bool>?

    // MARK: - Actions
    let onBeginEditing: () -> Void
    let onEndEditing: () -> Void
    let onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    let onCommit: () -> Void

    // MARK: - Proprerties
    private let keyboardOffset: CGFloat

    private let textAlignment: NSTextAlignment
    private let font: UIFont
    private let textColor: UIColor
    private let backgroundColor: UIColor
    private let contentType: UITextContentType?
    private let keyboardType: UIKeyboardType
    private let autocorrection: UITextAutocorrectionType
    private let autocapitalization: UITextAutocapitalizationType
    private let isSecure: Bool
    private let isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool
    private let placeholder: String?

    public static let defaultFont = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)

    private var hasDoneToolbar: Bool = false

    init(text: Binding<String>,
         isEditing: Binding<Bool>? = nil,
         keyboardOffset: CGFloat = 0,

         textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = .left,
         font: UIFont = UIKitTextField.defaultFont,
         textColor: UIColor = .black,
         backgroundColor: UIColor = .white,
         contentType: UITextContentType? = nil,
         keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default,
         autocorrection: UITextAutocorrectionType = .default,
         autocapitalization: UITextAutocapitalizationType = .none,
         isSecure: Bool = false,
         isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool = true,
         placeholder: String? = nil,

         hasDoneToolbar: Bool = false,

         onBeginEditing: @escaping () -> Void = { },
         onEndEditing: @escaping () -> Void = { },
         onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in },
         onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {

        self._text = text
        self.isEditing = isEditing

        self.keyboardOffset = keyboardOffset

        self.onBeginEditing = onBeginEditing
        self.onEndEditing = onEndEditing
        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
        self.onCommit = onCommit

        self.textAlignment = textAlignment
        self.font = font
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.contentType = contentType
        self.keyboardType = keyboardType
        self.autocorrection = autocorrection
        self.autocapitalization = autocapitalization
        self.isSecure = isSecure
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnabled
        self.placeholder = placeholder

        self.hasDoneToolbar = hasDoneToolbar
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {

        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.keyboardType = keyboardType
        textField.textAlignment = textAlignment
        textField.font = font
        textField.textColor = textColor
        textField.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        textField.textContentType = contentType
        textField.autocorrectionType = autocorrection
        textField.autocapitalizationType = autocapitalization
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = isSecure
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = isUserInteractionEnabled
        //textField.placeholder = placeholder
        if let placeholder = placeholder {
            textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(
                                    string: placeholder,
                                    attributes: [
                                        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray
                                    ])
        }

        textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        keyboardEvents.didShow = {
            if textField.isFirstResponder {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(350)) {
                    textField.adjustScrollView(offset: self.keyboardOffset, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }

        if hasDoneToolbar {
            textField.addDoneButton {
                print("Did tap Done Toolbar button")
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ textField: UITextField, context: Context) {

        textField.text = text

        if let isEditing = isEditing {
            if isEditing.wrappedValue {
                textField.becomeFirstResponder()
            } else {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        let parent: UIKitTextField

        init(_ parent: UIKitTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        @objc func valueChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
            parent.onEditingChanged(true)
        }

        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            parent.onBeginEditing()
            parent.onEditingChanged(true)
        }

        func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {

            //guard textField.text != "" || parent.shouldCommitIfEmpty else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.parent.isEditing?.wrappedValue = false
            }
            parent.text = textField.text ?? ""
            parent.onEditingChanged(false)
            parent.onEndEditing()
            parent.onCommit()
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            parent.isEditing?.wrappedValue = false
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            parent.onCommit()
            return true
        }
    }

}

extension UIView {

    func adjustScrollView(offset: CGFloat, animated: Bool = false) {

        if let scrollView = findParent(of: UIScrollView.self) {
            let contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + offset)
            scrollView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: animated)
        } else {
            print("View is not in ScrollView - do not adjust content offset")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is sample EmailRule implementation

```
class EmailRule : RegexRule {

    static let regex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

    public convenience init(message : String = "Email address is invalid"){
        self.init(regex: EmailRule.regex, message: message)
    }

    override func validate(_ value: String) -> Bool {
        guard value.count > 0 else { return true }

        return super.validate(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does `LoginViewModel` have an `@ObservedObject` property that is itself a `LoginViewModel`? And why does it have a `body` property? I think you have some copy-paste errors.

Comment: It is mistyped, it should be LoginView. I will correct it

Comment: What is your question exactly? It is a bit unclear... you could add sections in the question when it is long, using markdown flavour with hash signs #, ##, ### for section, sub section and subsubsection.

Comment: Also try shaving off more code from the example... can you try to focus the question with a more minimum working example?

Comment: I would rather to place all working example for others to be able to test it. I've recurring problems with implementing reusable TextFields, that are wrapped in Views (aimed to customise them) and have added Validator component I've pasted above. To store state of input and validation I am using ObservableObject. I am trying to understand why this solution is unreliable in SwiftUI. Why placing this reusable LabeledInput() and injecting input + validation into this view loses  input value, loses validation, or doesn't refresh validation correctly. It seems this is correct SwiftUI approach

Comment: Moreover it works differently for different type of TextFields. on the same screen LoginView, LabeledInput backed by TextField works differently than SecureField (here are problems with validation) and differently than UIKitTextField wrapper

Comment: Post the bare minimum code not the entire logic. It would make it easier to understand the problem. Be specific about the exact problem.

Comment: It is bare minimum :) If I post some code snipper folks complain that it is not reproducible and how they can run it and check for errors. here are sample components to understand the solution. I have many custom rules for example  but here is just one example